# Android custom spinner SelectedItem

Tags: android, spinner

I made a spinner in which im using a arrayadapter to populate it with images and text. on OnItemSelected i want to select only and only the text not the image.

Here is my code for the MainActivity.java

```
ArrayList<ItemData> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new ItemData("Select Plan Category",R.drawable.ic_bars));
list.add(new ItemData("Hookah",R.drawable.ic_006_hookah));
list.add(new ItemData("Drinks",R.drawable.ic_005_pint));
list.add(new ItemData("Gedi",R.drawable.ic_004_racing));
list.add(new ItemData("Snacks",R.drawable.ic_003_chips));
list.add(new ItemData("Shopping",R.drawable.ic_002_cart));
list.add(new ItemData("Bownling",R.drawable.ic_001_bowling));

SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.categoryText,list);
categorySpinnerjava.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my code for the ItemData.java

```
public class ItemData {

    private String planCategorytext = "";
    Integer imageId;

    public ItemData(String text, Integer imageId)
    {
        this.planCategorytext=text;
        this.imageId=imageId;
    }

    public String getPlanCategorytext() {
        return planCategorytext;
    }

    public void setPlanCategorytext(String planCategorytext) {
        this.planCategorytext = planCategorytext;
    }

    public Integer getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(Integer imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
}
```

And here is my code for the SpinnerAdapter.java(that is extending the ArrayAdapter

```
int groupid;
Activity getActivity;
ArrayList<ItemData> list;

LayoutInflater inflater;

public SpinnerAdapter(Activity context, int groupid, int id, ArrayList<ItemData> list) {
    super(context, id,list);

    this.list=list;
    inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.groupid=groupid;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(groupid,parent,false);

    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryVector);
    imageView.setImageResource(list.get(position).getImageId());

    TextView textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryText);
     textView.setText(list.get(position).getPlanCategorytext());


     return itemView;
}
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    return getView(position,convertView,parent);
}
```

I want to only select the text not the image. And when i normally do the

```
String spinnerselection = categorySpinnerjava.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

It gives me a output of "applicationpackage.ItemData@randomnumbers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected spinner item's text in the following way:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
            String selectedText=list.get(pos).getPlanCategorytext();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

**OR**

```
String selectedItemText=list.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).getPlanCategorytext();
```

Where list is the arraylist with ItemData which you used above to populate the data in spinner.

Also about this:

```
String spinnerselection = categorySpinnerjava.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

You have to replace `categorySpinnerjava.getSelectedItem().toString();` with `list.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).getPlanCategorytext();`

Comment: i used the String selectedText=list.get(pos).getPlanCategorytext();
but it asked me to declare the ArrayList final.
It works but what difference did the declaration of arraylist to final makes?

Comment: Making final will ensure that the field is a constant and cannot change. This will guarantees that the value used at any location in the method refers to the value passed.

Comment: @UjjwalBassi, if its working, please accept as answer.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting this error because

> "applicationpackage.ItemData@randomnumbers"

your **`categorySpinnerjava.getSelectedItem();`** return your model class **`ItemData`** not a `String`

Try this

```
ItemData itemData = (ItemData) categorySpinnerjava.getSelectedItem();
String data= itemData.getPlanCategorytext();
Integer imageId = itemData.getImageId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing using `Interface`.

Set text data inside `SpinnerAdapter` and extend `Interface` in `Activity` class to get the selected text

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
String spinnerselection = ((ItemData) categorySpinnerjava.getSelectedItem()).getPlanCategorytext();
```

Didn't try it yet, but in theory it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`Override getItem()` in your adapter. Cause `getSelectedItem()` return :

> `adapter.getItem(position);`

```
@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
 ItemData spinnerselection = (ItemData)categorySpinnerjava.getSelectedItem();
String plan = spinnerselection.getPlanCategorytext();
```